# Count the number of Connected Components (or the number of identified object) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

The object-based method described [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_objects#label_objects) helps uniquely label the hotspot in image objects.

```
// Uniquely label the hotspot image objects.
var objectId = hotspots.connectedComponents({
  connectedness: ee.Kernel.plus(1),
  maxSize: 128
});
```

If each object now has a unique ID, my question is how to print out all the labels and count the number of unique IDs that have been identified?

Answer (score 1):

reduceRegion with a countDistinct reducer.

```
var count = objectId.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.countDistinct(), ...})
```

Comment: Thank you! @Noel Gorelick

Comment: @Noel Gorelick I have used this approach but I am getting different numbers of clusters and labels: clusters: 238
labels: 4028. Shouldn't the cluster and labels be the same?

Comment: You should start a new question if you're having issues, so we can see your code.